# Excel freezes when excecuting a cycle of calculating an integral

Tags: excel, vba

The following task is given: to calculate the dose rate of a spherical radiation source using double integrals. I wrote a function, but unfortunately when I try to process it with 0.1 precision, Excel freezes. When the precision decreases, Excel processes it, but I don’t know if my teacher will be satisfied with such a solution to the problem. I can't figure out if my loop is wrong, or if Excel can't process such a large amount of data. Thank everyone in advance for your answer!

```
Function EqSphrPol(Th, Ph, Xk, Yk)
Application.MultiThreadedCalculation.Enabled =  True
R = 1
Xa = 4
Ya = 2
Za = 1
Zk = 1
L = (Xa - Xk) ^ 2 + (Ya - Yk) ^ 2
RSp = L + R ^ 2 * Sin(Th) ^ 2 - 2 * R * Sqr(L) * Sin(Th) * Cos(Ph) + (Za - Zk + R * Cos(Th)) ^ 2
EqSphrPol = (R ^ 2 * Sin(Th)) / RSp
End Function

Function Int1SphrPol(Ph, Xk, Yk)
N = 10: S2 = 0: Eps = 0.1 'Eps-variable of precision
Do
 St = (3.141) / N
 S1 = S2
 For M = 1 To N
  S2 = S2 + EqSphrPol(0 + M * St, Ph, Xk, Yk)
 Next
 S2 = St * S2
 N = 2 * N
Loop Until Abs(S1 - S2) <= Eps
Int1SphrPol = S2
End Function


Function Int2SphrPol(Xk, Yk)
R = 1
G = 8.46 * 10 ^ (-17)
ActS = 12 / (4 * 3.141 * R ^ 2)
N2 = 10: S22 = 0: Eps = 0.1
Do
 St2 = (3.141) / N2
 S11 = S22
 For K = 1 To N2
  S22 = S22 + Int1SphrPol(0 + K * St2, Xk, Yk)
 Next
 S22 = St2 * S22
 N2 = 2 * N2
Loop Until Abs(S11 - S22) <= Eps
S22 = S22 * ActS * G
Int2SphrPol = S22
End Function
```

1. Tried waiting. I waited for 2 hours. Nothing happened.
2. Disabling screen update. Nothing happened.
3. Using another method of calculating an integral(Trapezoidal, Simpson's method). Nothing happened either.
4. Decreasing a precision. It helps, but anyway, i don't think that it is a proper solution.

Comment: <.. rate of a spherical .. using double integrals. >  .. isn't spherical is a 3d space n we need 3 integrals?

Comment: You might be getting yourself into an infinite loop somehow. Maybe add some `Debug.Print` statements to write the value of your key variable to the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G) to check how the value is evolving and if it gets stuck. Also, if you add `DoEvents` inside your loop during debugging, it will allow you to use `Ctrl+Break` to stop VBA's excecution and check how things are going.

Comment: @p._phidot_ , well, it's complicated. Technically it's a flat sphere with such height that we can ignore, and using this double integral we're getting a surface area of that "sphere", which we will then multiply by surface activity and only then we will get a quantity of dose, that radiates from this sphere in Gy/s.

Comment: @DecimalTurn, thank you very much! Well, it looks like it stucks on peak values, but I still don't know what to do with it.
My console looks like this(last 15 rows or so):
 0,845199188080506 
 0,98237730142957 
 0,98237730142957 
 0,845199188080506 
 0,661046275099477 
 0,498594482741543 
 0,375814224395313 
 0,287531617003148 
 0,224406321526173 
 0,17871169441151 
 0,132529307136705 
 0,127062059664198 
 0,117942235535394 
 0,460908829060481 
 0,160103156161734 
 27,4919959247482 
 29,66506471273 
 31,8403215870147

Comment: 2 thing ( in my personal chklist ) [1] ACCURACY of formula transfer. dose rate calculation is normally quite straight forward. I mean.. there is a formula.. plug in.. n just use. I'd normally test those formula's in normal excel spreadsheet 1st..  before using it in any coding.. test and prove that each function really CAN deliver the computation.. before running it in a loop. [2] LOOP control. in ur loops.. u use `Abs(a - b) <= Eps` twice, where b is (afaik) is always growing.

Comment: if ur test @ [1] is proven (I mean function delivers intended when it was called separately), then i (again.. afaik), suspect the the threshold was overshoot at 1 stage of the loop and lead to infinite loop. Eg, a = 0 , b = 2, Abs(a - b) > 0.1 , run, nxt  a = 2 , b = 4, Abs(a - b) > 0.1 , run again.. and so on.. | @DecimalTurn highlights a way to trace the values [1] via debugger.. I' just propose to do the same thing via spreadsheet. bear in mind checks for [2] can only starts after [1] chk is done.

Comment: This heavily smells like an accuracy problem. I would advise you to write as much as useful information to an outputfile (logfile) and see where you get stuck.